# in multiple input type file always first condition satsify but not second while working with two different input type file which is multiple

Tags: codeigniter

```
Below is my html code

 <input type="file" name="user_img[]"    multiple >

 <input type="file" name="user_video[]"  multiple >
```

when i am selecting video it show image condition only.

Below script for controller method but everytime it echo image even video selected  here image and video are multiple type

```
if(!empty($_FILES['user_img']['name'])){
echo 'image';
}
 elseif(!empty($_FILES['user_video']['name'])){
                echo 'video';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

yah after checking just little condition i got a solution.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['user_img']['name']) && empty($_FILES['user_video']['name'])){
echo 'image';
}

elseif(!empty($_FILES['user_video']['name']) && empty($_FILES['user_img']['name'])){
                echo 'video';
            }
```